# ¿Por qué me sale ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Soy nuevo programando y todavía no controlo muy bien python, así que agradecería que me ayudarais.

Con este programa (que esta inacabado) quiero conseguir sumar dos listas de números, pero creo que al convertir cada carácter en `int()`, me da error; es decir, al hacer `suma=int(i)+int(e)`. Os dejo una foto del error que me aparece.

***Mesaje de error:***

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

***Ejecucion del programa:***

```
Este funciona
------------------------------------------  
Introduce lista de numeros: 2
Introduce lista de numeros: 3
5
------------------------------------------

Arroja error
------------------------------------------  
Introduce lista de numeros: 2 3
Introduce lista de numeros: 3 2
5
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
------------------------------------------
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Codigo:***

```
def sumar (sum1, sum2):
    sum1.split()
    sum2.split()
    if len(sum1)>=len(sum2):
        kont=''
        for  i in sum1:
            for e in sum2:
                suma=int(i)+int(e)
                suma=str(suma)
                suma=suma+kont 
                kont=suma
        return kont


a=str(input('Introduce lista de numeros:'))
b=str(input('introduce lista de numeros:'))
print(sumar(a, b))
```

Comment: Creo que el error, es porque no puede convertir una cadena vacia a un entero. A ver que opinan los phytoneros de la comunidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes algunos errores en el código.

- `sum1.split()` divide la cadena `sum1` por donde haya espacios, y *te devuelve* una lista con el el resultado. No modifica la variable `sum1`, que sigue siendo la cadena original. Por eso cuando haces más adelante `for i in sum1`, en lugar de iterar por cada número de una lista (como seguramente pretendías) lo que haces es iterar *por cada caracter de la cadena `sum1`*. Así que cuando llega al carácter `' '` la conversión a `int()` falla, pues un espacio blanco no puede convertirse en `int`.

  Lo que tienes que hacer es recoger el resultado de `.split()` en otra variable, por ejemplo `lista1 = sum1.split()`, y luego iterar por esta.
- Los bucles anidados no son seguramente lo que querías. Suponiendo que lo de `sum1` estuviera bien y fuese una lista de números, al iterar primero por `sum1`, y luego dentro por `sum2`, lo que haces es que para el primer elemento de `sum1`, iteras por todos los elementos de `sum2`, y luego para el segundo elemento de `sum1` vuelves a iterar por todos los elementos de `sum2`, etc.

  Es decir, por ejemplo, si `sum1` tuviera los números 1 y 2, mientras que `sum2` tiene 3 y 4, tus bucles anidados harían primero 1+3, después 1+4, después 2+3 y finalmente 2+4. Sospecho que no es eso lo que buscabas.

  Para arreglarlo, en lugar de bucles anidados debes iterar *en paralelo*, ya que entiendo que lo que quieres es sumar el primer elemento de ambas listas, después el segundo elemento de ambas, el tecero, etc..

  No me queda claro si quieres que el resultado sea otra lista cuyos elementos sean esas sumas, o quieres simplemente la suma total de todos los elementos. En este segundo caso puede ser más sencillo, ya que puedes sumar todos los elementos de la primera lista y después todos los de la segunda.a
- Finalmente, las conversiones a `str()` de la variable `suma` no las entiendo. En la línea `suma=suma+kont` , si `suma` valía por ejemplo `"4"` y `kont` valía `"5"` al "sumarlas" en realidad las estás concatenando, con lo que el resultado sería `"45"` y no `"9"`. Supongo que lo quieres es el 9, por lo que no tienes que convertirlo en `str()`.

Te pongo el código corregido en dos casos, según cuál sea el objetivo buscado.

### Caso 1: El resultado es la suma total

Como dije más arriba, en este caso lo más fácil es iterar por cada lista separadamente e ir sumando los valores a un acumulador total.

```
def sumar (datos1, datos2):
    lista1 = datos1.split()
    lista2 = datos2.split()
    suma = 0
    for a in lista1:
      suma = suma + int(a)
    for b in lista2:
      suma = suma + int(b)
    return suma

print(sumar("1 2", "3 4"))
```

```
10
```

No he querido usar sintaxis avanzada, ya que estás empezando, pero como curiosidad para cuando sepas más, todo eso podria haberse resuelto en una línea de código, haciendo uso de una expresión generadora (una expresión que tiene un `for` dentro y que genera secuencias de datos) y de la función `sum()` que tiene python y que te devuelve la suma de todos los elementos de una secuencia:

```
def suma(datos1, datos2):
   return sum(int(a) for a in datos1.split()) \
        + sum(int(b) for b in datos2.split())
```

### Caso 2: El resultado es una lista con las sumas de los elementos

Aquí supongo que buscas que la función retorne una lista en la que el elemento 0 sea la suma de los elementos 0 de entrada, y así sucesivamente.

Ya que tenemos que iterar por ambas listas en paralelo, resulta más sencillo en este caso iterar por un índice `i` que vaya tomando valores `0`, `1`, etc. y sea usado para acceder a `lista1[i]+lista2[i]`, así siempre se accede a elementos "emparejados" de ambas listas. Este enfoque requiere que las dos listas sean de la misma longitud, por lo que habrá que verificarlo en el código.

```
def sumar(datos1, datos2):
    lista1 = datos1.split()
    lista2 = datos2.split()
    if len(lista1) != len(lista2):
       print("No se pueden sumar listas de diferente longitud")
       return []    # Retornar, por ejemplo, una lista vacía para este caso
    # El resultado será otra lista. De momento la creamos vacía
    # para ir añadiendo elementos a ella a medida que los calculemos
    resultado = []
    for i in range(len(lista1)):
       resultado.append(int(lista1[i]) + int(lista2[i]))
    return resultado

print(sumar("1 2", "3 4"))
```

```
[4, 6]
```

Finalmente, si lo que buscabas es que el resultado tuviera el mismo formato que las entradas (es decir, una cadena con los números separados por espacios), puedes usar el operador `str.join()` para convertir la lista resultante en la cadena buscada, así:

```
r = sumar("1 2", "3 4")
cadena = " ".join(str(n) for n in r)
print(cadena)
```

```
4 6
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Tu explicación me ha sido de gran ayuda y ahora tengo todo mucho mas claro. Da gusto que te respondan de esta manera!!!